# Why ruby can't save file to special path with wget?

Tags: python, ruby, file, terminal, wget

If I use wget in the terminal:

```
$ wget file_url -O files/file
```

It works.

But if I run it with ruby:

```
system("wget file_url -O files/file")
# Or
`wget file_url -O files/file`
```

It saved the file to the current path, but not into the `files` folder. Why?

---

## Edit (Add python pattern)

Even I tried python, the same result:

```
import os

os.system("wget {0} -O files/{1}".format(file_url, file))
```

The file saved into the current path.

Comment: can't reproduce, works fine on 2.3.1.

Comment: @Anthony I also using 2.3.1

Comment: By the way, I am on Mac.

Comment: What do you get in your terminal when you call "type wget"?

Comment: @EricDuminil `wget is /usr/local/bin/wget`

Answer (score 1):

## Dir.chdir

Without understand where the problem comes from, you could use `system` in the desired folder with [`Dir.chdir`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Dir.html#method-c-chdir) :

```
Dir.chdir 'path' do
  system("wget --quiet url -O file")
  # Example :
  system("wget --quiet https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png -O google_logo.png")
end
```

## Curl instead of wget

I've had problems with `wget` on Mac OS X. `curl` should be installed by default :

```
system("curl url -o path/filename")
system("curl url -o path/filename -s") # quiet version, without progress bar
```

This worked fine on my system, after having created the `path` folder :

```
system("curl https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png -o path/google_logo.png -s")
```

Comment: Thank you. I don't why it works under the terminal. But not work in ruby. I also tried python, the same result. I will paste the python source on the topic.